# NG-Zorro Datepicker Manual Input Mask not working

Tags: angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd, ngx-mask, ng-zorro-mobile

I need to mask the datepicker as `MM/dd/yyyy` and my users do not want to manually type out the `/`character. They want to be able to enter in just the numbers and the masking works on its own.

I have tried `ngx-mask` and while this works great for inputs, it doesn't work for the datepicker.

Here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-ivy-xpzkoi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) which I have set the mask but it isn't working as expected

```
  <nz-date-picker
    mask="'d0/00/0000'"
    [nzFormat]="'dd/MM/yyyy'"
  ></nz-date-picker>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`? I see both intents in your code here and in your stackblitz example

Comment: Yea I need MM/dd/yyyy. Neither one works btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems folks at `ng-zorro` have already received similar requests, and they have made their stance [clear](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/6860) that they won't support masking natively and since `Datepicker` is a component that creates an input internally the mask can't be added like a regular input.

So, the approach in `codesandbox` linked in the question is correct.
We would need to create and enable the `mask` on a custom input field.

The primary issue I noticed was that by default `ngx-mask` doesn't capture the special characters of the mask such as the `/` in this example.
So a date of `09/09/2023` would be captured as `09092023` which isn't accepted as a valid date by the `ng-zorro` date picker.

You could fix this with the `dropSpecialCharacters` option for `ngx-mask`. However, during my attempts, there were issues with the `date` and `mask` getting messed up for some inputs, and looking at their github, there are multiple times that people have encountered similar issues.

Therefore, I used the [Maskito](https://github.com/taiga-family/maskito) library which although relatively new has seen good results, and works well with this use case. Although you could use another library or create a custom directive.

Here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-ivy-f5cn3g) with the Maskito library to provide masking and using `MM/dd/yyyy` format for the date inputs.

Comment: Beautiful Job my friend. You get the prize